# IntelliJ cannot resolve Kotlin stdlib members within bundle

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin, osgi

According to [the Kotlin docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/kotlin-osgi.html), there is an OSGi bundle for the Kotlin standard libraries. However, if I replace `kotlin-stdlib` with this bundle as recommended:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
    <artifactId>kotlin-osgi-bundle</artifactId>
    <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
    <type>bundle</type>
</dependency>
```

IntelliJ is no longer able to find any classes or functions from the stdlib (i.e. `println`):

[image: Screenshot]

If I build and run the project (with `maven-pax-plugin`), everything works fine - it just seems to have broken IntelliJ's analysis capabilities.

How should I properly include Kotlin as an OSGi dependency?

I am using `maven-bundle-plugin` to build this bundle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove the type section, it should work:

```
<type>bundle</type>
```

The Kotlin OSGi bundle **is not** a Maven bundle artifact.

For Intellij IDEA 2018.2, works for me, using this way :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-osgi-bundle</artifactId>
        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I thought of this and tried it, however, I still have the same issue :/

Comment: Works for 2017.3. Are you using version 2018.2? I updated the answer for that version.

Comment: Yes, but this also compiles the non-bundle stdlib, and I'm not sure if that's appropriate, unless these are also auto-bundled (but then there'd be no point in including `kotlin-osgi-bundle`, would there?)

Comment: Looking inside the artifact, I strongly advise to **use Kotlin OSGi**. Otherwise the Kotlin dependencies for your bundle get unversioned. That additional dependency to make Intellij happy, **does not get bundled inside**.